# reactJS map function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS application where I am trying to dynamically render  some data that I read in with a fetch() promise.  This is the code of my application:

```
    import React from 'react'; 
import '../styles/app.css'; 

//think of react components as functions 
class Testpage2 extends React.Component { 

constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
        numberOfRecords: 0,
        productArray: [{
            barcode: '',
            name: ''
        }]
    }; 

}  

componentDidMount() { 

    let currentComponent = this; 
    var recordCount = 0;
    var tempData = [];

    //Make use of the API not the web service. 
    let url = "http://wmjwwebapi-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/getdata"; 
    const options = { method: 'GET' }; 

    fetch(url, options) 
    .then(function(response) { 
        return response.json(); 
    }) 
    .then(function(myJson) { 
        if (myJson == undefined) 
        { 
        console.log("fetch failed"); 
        } 
    else 
    { 
        //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned 
        var return_code = myJson[0].return_code; 
        if (return_code == "Default Return code"){ 
            recordCount = -2; 
        } else { 
            tempData = JSON.parse(myJson[0].return_string);
            recordCount = tempData.barcode.length; 
        }
        currentComponent.setState(
        {
            numberOfRecords: recordCount,
            productArray: currentComponent.state.productArray.push(
            { 
                name: tempData.name, 
                barcode: tempData.barcode 
            })
        }
    );
    } 
    }); 
} 

render() { 
    console.log(this.state.productArray);
    return ( 
        <div> 
            { this.state.productArray.map((prod, index) => <li key={index}>{prod.barcode}</li>)}
        </div> 
    ) 
} 
} 

export default Testpage2
```

and this is the error message that I am getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.productArray.map is not a function
at Testpage2.render (testpage2.js:67)
```

This is the result of the console.log() that I added in the render() function:

[image]

I'm not really sure what this error is telling me or how to go about debugging the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me what the result is when you console.log "this.state.productArray" in the render function?

Comment: I edited the post to include an image from the console.log()

Comment: Thanks but I already answered your question... Can you confirm that it works then?

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you check that `Array.isArray(this.state.productArray)` is `true`?

Comment: I updated my answer, to follow a best practice... You may want to incorporate this update into your code as well @JonathanSmall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React .map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574367/react-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I jumped to my conclusion to quickly.  While the error message is no longer being generated, only 1 instance is being rendered.If you look at the image in the post, you will see that there are values in this.state.productArray.barcode[0], [1], and [2] but the only value that gets rendered when I execute the code is this.state.productArray.barcode[2].  Why wouldnt the map function execute on each element of the this.state.productArray array?

Comment: There are so many questions raised with same problem in stackoverflow and obviously every question has n no of answers provided. Please do research about these problems in the internet. Please mark these questions as duplicate rather than answering.

Comment: Jonathan you are directly mapping data in render you need to do conditional check in render like { this.state.productArray && this.state.productArray!= undefined && this.state.productArray.map. Please have a look at stack overflow Solutions. Plenty of Solutions out there for this issue

Comment: @Think-Twice I'm actually in the process of changing the map to call a function to render as opposed to rendering inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of array.push is the new length of the array aka a number

So you set the state property productArray to a number and then try to call number.map which is not defined

How to fix?

push first and then use that array to set the state

```
const updatedArray = [...currentComponent.state.productArray] 
updatedArray.push({ name: tempData.name, barcode: tempData.barcode })

currentComponent.setState({
   numberOfRecords: recordCount,
   productArray: updatedArray
}
```

Resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify the state manually. The recommended way is always to use `setState` method.

Comment: Nice one buddy.

Comment: Still better way of push elements to an array in React is currentComponent.setState(prevState =>({productArray: [...prevState.productArray, { name: tempData.name, barcode: tempData.barcode }]}));

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length** of the array.

It appears that your code expects that `Array.push()` will return the modified array itself:

```
productArray: currentComponent.state.productArray.push(...
```

To prevent the state corruption you should do construct the new array separately, before invoking `setState()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array's push()` function [returns integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value), so you cannot call `map()` function on it. Try to change your function to:

```
currentComponent.setState({
  numberOfRecords: recordCount,
  productArray: [...currentComponent.state.productArray, { 
    name: tempData.name, 
    barcode: tempData.barcode 
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `Array.push` method does not return the modified array, it returns the new *length* of the array, which is a number. Numbers in JavaScript do not have the `map` method.

You need to do first create a clone of the `productArray`, then push the new data, and finally set state:

```
const newProductArray = [...currentComponent.state.productArray]
newProductArray.push({ 
    name: tempData.name, 
    barcode: tempData.barcode 
})
currentComponent.setState(
    {
        numberOfRecords: recordCount,
        productArray: newProductArray
    }
)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Still better way of push elements to an array in React is currentComponent.setState(prevState =>({productArray: [...prevState.productArray: { name: tempData.name, barcode: tempData.barcode }]}));

Comment: Do you have a source for that syntax @Think-Twice? I've never seen `:` used in an array, as far as I know it's reserved for objects.

Comment: Sorry it’s typo mistake it should be comma not colon